# How can I insert parts of an array into MySQL?

Tags: mysql, arrays, perl

I have an array in Perl like the following (only much bigger). My array is called @sqlInsert

> Element1
> A
> B
> C
>
> Element2
> A
> B
> C
>
> Element3
> A
> B
> C

I want to fill a MySQL table with the information in this data. So really, I want to have one row going:

```
 for ($count=0; $count<@arrayInsert; $count++) {
      INSERT INTO table values ("sqlInsert[$i]","sqlInsert[$i+1]","sqlInsert[$i+2]","sqlInsert[$i+3]")
 }
```

Any pointers?

Comment: The button with the binary on it means "format as code".

Answer (score 3):

Use [DBI placeholders](http://search.cpan.org/~timb/DBI/DBI.pm#Placeholders_and_Bind_Values) and...

...an array slice:

```
 my $sth = $dbh->prepare( 'INSERT INTO table VALUES ( ?, ?, ?, ? )' );

 $sth->execute( @sqlInsert[ $n .. $m ] );
```

...or a splice:

```
 while( @sqlInsert ) {
      $sth->execute( splice @sqlInsert, 0, $length, () );
      }
```

It might be easier to create a data structure, such as an array of arrays, that already groups the elements for each structure:

```
 foreach my $ref ( @sqlInsert ) {
      $sth->execute( @$ref );
      }
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Brian ... I went with your first solution. However, here is the error, I get:

>Use of uninitialized value in range (or flop) at sqlInsert.pl line 56.
>Use of uninitialized value in range (or flop) at sqlInsert.pl line 56.
>Argument "" isn't numeric in array slice at sqlInsert.pl line 56.
>DBD::mysql::st execute failed: called with 1 bind variables when 4 are needed at sqlInsert.pl line 56.

Here is my line 56:

> $sth->execute( @td[ $n .. $m ] );

Comment: I ordered a crystal ball from Amazon. When it gets here, I'll look at your code. :)

Comment: Fair enough buddy, I probably deserved that:

>#Auth
>$platform = "mysql";
>$database = "db";
>$host = "localhost";
>$user = "root";

>#Connect to DB
>$DBIconnect = DBI->connect($dsn, $user);

>my $sth = $DBIconnect->prepare( 'INSERT INTO table VALUES ( ?, ?, ?, ? )' );
>$sth->execute( @sqlInsert[ $n .. $m ] ); 

------

Can you let me know what the $n ... $m does?

Comment: You might want to start with _Learning Perl_ if you need to pick up the basics. I'm not going to try to read code in comments. Update your question with code.

Comment: @poutine: twice in one day I've pointed you to the documentation: please look up `..` in [perldoc perlop](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html). If you have never done so before, type `perldoc perl` at the command line and marvel at all the documentation that is ready at your fingertips.

Comment: Thanks Ether .. I'll take a look. I was just being appreciative in my previous post, but I guess you've taken it for me being lazy. I can't change that, but I appreciate the advice.

Comment: @poutine: I hadn't seen your previous note (I have now). It's okay to be a beginner, so long as you know what steps you need to take to progress beyond that point. Good luck on your happy Perl journey :)